# @Autowired dependency in jackson deserializer converter with Spring Boot 2.1.0 is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, autowired

I want to autowire a spring dependency into a jackson deserialization converter. E.g.,

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter;

 @Component
 public class LookupConverter extends StdConverter<T, T> {

    @Autowired
    private Repository<T> repo;

    @Override
    public IsoCountry convert(T value) {
        repo.findById(value.getId()).orElse(value);
    }
}
```

I have tried using: `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` e.g.,

```
public LookupConverter() {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}
```

but get the following message

> Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of LookupConverter: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.

I have tried injecting a `SpringHandlerInstantiator` into the the `ObjectMapper` ala [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393599/autowiring-in-jsondeserializer-springbeanautowiringsupport-vs-handlerinstantiat) and [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/685)

```
@Bean
public HandlerInstantiator handlerInstantiator(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    return new SpringHandlerInstantiator(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
}

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder(HandlerInstantiator handlerInstantiator) {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.handlerInstantiator(handlerInstantiator);
    return builder;
}
```

This also does not work, seemingly because the `SpringHandlerInstantiator` is not being used and my custom `Converter` is not being instantiated by spring.

Any pointers to how this can be accomplished using Spring Boot 2.1.0 would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.  Could Spring possibly know what to inject if you've got your repository defined as generic?  Do you have any qualifiers attached to the *explicit* repository you want to use?

Comment: Yes, I tried with explicit `@Qualifier`s and it still doesn't work. The issue seems to be that The converters are not being managed by spring

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I have a similar problem with custom deserializer and injecting SpringHandlerInstantiator doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I ended up going with the static autowiring method which strikes me as a bit gross, but does work. E.g., `private static MyRepo repo` and an `@Autowired` setter

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this issue would be to create `@Service` that provides repository or repositories in a static way, for example:

```
@Service
public class RepositoryService {

    @Resource
    private ExampleEntityRepository repo;

    @Getter
    private static final Map<Class<?>, Repository<?, ?>> repos = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        repos.put(ExampleEntity.class, repo);
    }

}
```

Then instead of injecting repo to your converter you would do something like:

```
private Repository<ExampleEntity, Long> repo = RepositoryService.getRepos()
                                                       .get(ExampleEntity.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try the static approach and it works but it feels too much like a hack for my liking